# Uniform distribution-Mean, Standard deviation

Tags: probability

The thickness x of a protective coating applied to a conductor designed to work in corrosive conditions follows a uniform distribution ober the interval [20,40] microns. Find the mean, standard deviation and cumulative distribution function of the thickness of the protective coating. Find the probability the coating is less than 35 microns thick.

Mean:

$E[X]= \mu = \frac{b+a}{2}=30$
Standard deviation:

$\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{12}}=\frac{20}{\sqrt{12}}$

PDF:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x < 20 \\ \frac{1}{20} & 20 \leq x \leq 40 \end{cases}$$

By definition the CDF:

$\int_{-\infty}^{t=x} f(t) dt$

$\int_{20}^{t=x} \frac{t}{20} \vert_{20}^{t=x}=\frac{x}{20}-1$

Comment: Substitute $x=35$ to finish the question.  $$P(X<35) = \frac34$$